# C# Give an constructor internal value

Tags: c#, object, constructor

I am trying to give a class an object which don’t have control over it. That mean if the main class change the object, the class I’ve created have also the changes.

Example:

```
class main
{
   private string test;

   public main()
   {
      var Test = new Test(test);
   }
}
```

If I change now the string “test” the object Test should also see the change string. Is that possible?

Comment: What u expected???????

Comment: add an event to the setter of the test string, and subscribe in the test object to update when raised.

Comment: that doesn't sound like a good design. what are you trying to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to do if you instead of string use a specially crafted class:

```
public class SharedData
{
   public string Test {get;set;}
}
```

Then if you have an object of type `SharedData` instead of string, they will share the value. Strings are immutable in C#, so you wont' have the same string reference in both classes.

```
class main
{
   private SharedData test = new ShareData();

   public main()
   {
      var Test = new Test(test);
   }
}
```

P.S. It's a different question whether this is a good design or not. It's hard to answer based on the examples you have provided. I would avoid such design if possible and rather pass string as parameter where you need it to have less state. But as always it depends and there can be cases where what you do is beneficial, but you can consider changing the design to make it easier.